# Какая модель памяти используется в AMD64 архитектуре?

Tags: архитектура, память, x86-64

Подскажите какая модель памяти используется в 64 битной архитектуре и в чём её отличие от 32 битной? Также где можно подробно почитать про трансляцию адресов?

Comment: Танненбаума почитайте

Comment: Почитать про все, касающееся AMD, можно в фирменной документации AMD, которая лежит на сайте AMD. А на русский, скорее всего, это не переводилось.

Comment: В архитектуре в целом или именно в настоящем 64-битном режиме, который так же именуется long mode. В котором по факту обычная плоская модель, без сегментных регистров